# How to get a payment information from magento api?

Tags: php, magento, soap, magento-1.4, magento-1.5

```
$proxy = new SoapClient('http://magentolocal.com/mag/api/soap/?wsdl');
$sessionId = $proxy->login('test', 'test123');
$getorderid = "100000054";
$getdetails = $proxy->call($sessionId, 'sales_order.info', $getorderid);
print_r($getdetails);
```

it is return an array, it contain a payment_id,so where can i pass a payment_id and get a payment information of that order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento don't have API methods to work with payments, but there is some usefull methods to work with invoices - http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/doc/webservices-api/api#mage_sales

Comment: Actual i am creating a quickbook for magento,i want to display a payment information of that order,so i use a magento api to sync order,there is anyother way to get this?